# Contact Form 7 (WordPress plugin): Redirect AND Tracking

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, wordpress, redirect

I can both manage to redirect to another URL using:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

Documented here: http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

and track form submissions using:

```
on_sent_ok: "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact Form', 'Submit']);"
```

Documented here: http://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/

Unfortunately, I can't get both of them to work together. What I have tried this far is:

```
on_sent_ok: "onSentOkFunc();"
function onSentOkFunc() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact Form', 'Submit']);
    window.location = "http://gohere.com";
}
```

...but that's not doing the trick. Has anyone else managed to successfully do this yet?

Comment: Is there any kind of js console error when you try your last method?

Comment: Not as far as I can see, no.